# Use of the chi-square test with low expected value

Tags: statistics

I have a question about the use of the chi-square test.

I've been told that use of the chi-squared test for independence requires that most of the expected values be over 5.

What is worrying is that the expected values in my experiment are 2 - what test of independence would be more appropriate here?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: What is confusing? I'll edit the post for clarity.

Comment: There are millions of chi-square tests and many tests of independence.  Which specific one are you using?  What do you mean by expected values?  As in a mean?  Of what?